# Error when starting cassandra with bin/cassandra -f

Tags: windows-7, cassandra

I've got the latest version of cassandra installed on my Windows 7 machine in the following directory:

```
/cygdrive/c/Development/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-1.1.4
```

All necessary directories have been created for data_file_directories, saved_caches_direcory, and commitlog_directory under /var/lib/cassandra but when I attempt to start it up using:

```
bin/cassandra -f
```

I get the following error:

> $ bin/cassandra -f
>   xss =  -ea -javaagent:bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
>   bin/cassandra: line 149: getopt: command not found
>   Error parsing arguments!

This isn't the first time I've seen this error, but I don't have this issue when stating cassandra on a Mac (same version).  Have I missed a configuration step somewhere on Windows as I'm following the 'Getting Started wiki' and I can't see anythign obvious.  My system have 4GB of ram so it should be able to cope just fine and I've not changed the values for the HEAP_SIZE and just left them commented out so that cassandra can choose how much it requires.

Any thoughts as to what's causing this error on startup?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra is not supported under cygwin, but bin\cassandra.bat is known to work under normal Windows cmd.  DataStax also distributes a native Windows installer (that will create a Windows service) at http://www.datastax.com/products/community.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't know cygwin wasn't supported and now I've got it running.